# Boolean Column as Tensorflow Feature Columns

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I like to add a boolean type column into the feature columns for the input layers. How can I do that? I can't find any class of tf.feature_column that I can treat the boolean type data. Thanks in advance!

```
CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
BOOLEAN_COLUMNS = 'G'

def one_hot_cat_column(feature_name, vocab):
  return tf.feature_column.indicator_column(
      tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(feature_name,
                                                 vocab))
feature_columns = []
for feature_name in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS:
  # Need to one-hot encode categorical features.
  vocabulary = df[feature_name].unique()
  feature_columns.append(one_hot_cat_column(feature_name, vocabulary))
```

Comment: Are you building a neural network? In that case I don't think you can work with boolean values at all.

Comment: Hi, can you please explain why I can't include boolean values?

Comment: because they are intractable? i mean you cant run derivatives on them, and neural networks work based on the gradient descent which requires intensive use of derivatives to find local minima

Comment: Thanks, I've changed them to binary